# Elegant way to prove that this vector set is linear independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm trying to find an elegant way to prove that this vector set $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}, ~~\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},~~\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},~~\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ is linearly independent. I tried to find the matrix determinant (Where the column vectors are these vectors) through co factors expansion. Also, I tried to reduce the matrix to find which vectors are linearly independent based on the pivots. Is there another way to prove such linear independence?

Comment: 1 - xi are independent obviously. Maybe a proof by contradiction?

Comment: Why is it obvious Mark?

Comment: They are the standard coordinate axis basis vectors

Comment: @Mark no they're not, those would be with just one 1 and 3 zero

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have said "obvious". See my answer for elaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your vectors be $v_4, v_3, v_2, v_1$, consider the vector $$\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^4 v_i =\mathbb{1},$$

the all one vector.

notice that $$\mathbb{1}-v_i=e_i,i\in \left\{1,2,3,4\right\}$$

the standard unit basis, hence they must be linearly independent.

Comment: :O Thank you Siong! Beautiful!

Comment: So it's because the vectors span a four dimensional space and a vector set is independent (in $R^4$) iff it spans four dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $v_i$ are dependent.

There are then $c_i$ such that $\sum c_i v_i = 0$ where $c_i$ not all zero.
Then subtract $(\sum c_i) \cdot 1 $ from both sides where $1$ is the vector with entries all 1.

$\sum c_i e_i = (\sum c_i) \cdot 1$

Deduce that the $c_i$ are all equal (see the vector equality entry by entry) and therefore they must all be zero (contradiction).

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard method $av_1+bv_2+cv_3+dv_4=\vec{0}$. If all coefficients vanish, then the vectors are linearly independent:

$a+b+c=0$

$a+b+d=0$

$a+c+d=0$

$b+c+d=0$

Solving this system is pretty easy. You will see that $a=b=c=d=0$, hence the vectors are linearly independent.

A More tricky way is to see that multiplication with:

$$\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&1&1&-2\\ 1&1&-2&1
\\ 1&-2&1&1\\ -2&1&1&1\end {array}
 \right] $$

will give a multiple of the identity matrix. Hence there exists an inverse which is the same as saying that all column vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you MrYouMath. I tried that but i'm looking for another way. I thought there was another way to do it, based on the matrix symmetry or based on  something different.  Thank you again.

Comment: Added more tricky Explanation but I would rather use the equations :D

Comment: :O! Thank you MrYouMath!

Answer (score 0):

You can observe that, if
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then
$$
M\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}=
3\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
M\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}=
-\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
M\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
M\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
The last two vectors are obviously linearly independent. Thus $M$ has eigenvalues $3$, $-1$ and $1$ (double), so it is invertible.

However, row reduction is much easier than cofactor expansion:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&& \begin{aligned}R_2&\gets R_2-R_1\\ R_3&\gets R_3-R_1\end{aligned}
\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_2\leftrightarrow R_3
\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_4\gets R_4+R_2
\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_4\gets R_4+R_3
\end{align}
so the determinant is $1\cdot(-1)\cdot(-1)\cdot 3=3$.